# Where are the canonical question for installing Ubuntu in a Apple hardware (macintosh)?

Tags: discussion

Seriously, I've found too many answers (contradictory or being exactly the same or just link-only answers) about this and none seems to be 100% precise in what needs to be done to complete the task.

Has anyone actually done this and have experience? I'm afraid to upvote an answer about this in fear that what I'm upvoting only works under certain circumstances or don't at all; or against what I should voting as duplicated.

Comment: I wouldn't wonder if people are trying Ask Different and not thinking about Ask Ubuntu. I agree, this is an area that *really* could use some work. Lots of people want to use Ubuntu on Macs, but as of right now, Ask Ubuntu is rather useless in this regard.